# How do I color multiple line of text under a specific paragraph in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to set a color of paragraphs without the use of selections of divs to basically style the paragraph. Could anyone help solve my issue with paragraph colors?

Basically, I want to use combinations or child sectors in CSS if possible to have multiple lines of paragraph to be a color under a belonging to the headers for example under h3 headers only show blue color paragraphs and h4 headers only show red color paragraphs.

```css
h3 {
  color: lime;
}

h3 ~ p {
  color: blue;
}

h4 {
  color: Orange;
}

h4 ~ p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h3>Heading 1</h3>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as blue...</p>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as blue...</p>

<h4>Heading 2</h4>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as red...</p>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as red...</p>

<h3>Heading 1 (Again)</h3>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as blue...</p>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as blue...</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `+` selector instead of `~` so you can target only the needed `p` and avoid specifity/order issue:

```css
h3 + p,
h3 + p + p{
    color: blue;
}

h4 + p,
h4 + p + p{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<h3>Heading 1</h3>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as blue...</p>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as blue...</p>

<h4>Heading 2</h4>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as red...</p>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as red...</p>

<h3>Heading 1 (Again)</h3>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as blue...</p>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as blue...</p>
```

Or you can consider a more complex selector using `~` if the number of `p` is undefined *(the order of the CSS is important here)*

```css
h3 ~ p{ /*target the first ones*/
    color: blue;
}

h4 ~ p{ /*target the next ones*/
    color: Orange;
}

h4 ~ h3 ~ p { /*target the last ones*/
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<h3>Heading 1</h3>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as blue...</p>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as blue...</p>

<h4>Heading 2</h4>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as orange...</p>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as orange...</p>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as orange...</p>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as orange...</p>

<h3>Heading 1 (Again)</h3>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as red...</p>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as red...</p>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as red...</p>
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if there are more than two paragraphs

Answer (score -2):

I found a very elegant and simple solution that will be helpful to me in the future. It uses jQuery, you might be able to pull it off in native JavaScript but the jQuery function makes it very simple.

```js
$("h3").nextUntil("h4").css({
  "color": "blue"
});
$("h4").nextUntil("h3").css({
  "color": "red"
});
```

```css
h3 {
  color: lime;
}

h4 {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as blue...</p>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as blue...</p>

<h4>Heading 2</h4>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as red...</p>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as red...</p>

<h3>Heading 1 (Again)</h3>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as blue...</p>
<p>This section of the paragraphs only to be shown as blue...</p>
```